# Goroutine Channel, Copy vs Pointer

Tags: go

Both functions are doing the same task which is initializing "Data struct". what are the Pros or Cons of each function? e.g. the function should unmarshal a big JSON file.

```
package main

type Data struct {
    i int
}

func funcp(c chan *Data) {
    var t *Data
    t = <-c //receive
    t.i = 10
}

func funcv(c chan Data) {
    var t Data
    t.i = 20
    c <- t //send
}

func main() {
    c := make(chan Data)
    cp := make(chan *Data)

    var t Data

    go funcp(cp)
    cp <- &t //send
    println(t.i)

    go funcv(c)
    t = <- c //receive
    println(t.i)
}
```

[Link to Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/JYUKuJ9rXan)

Comment: You cannot "swapp[...] receive/send form/to a goroutine channel". What is your question?

Comment: I corrected my question.

Answer (score 1):

The title of your question seems wrong.  You are asking not about *swapping* things but rather about whether to send a *pointer to some data* or a *copy of some data*.  More importantly, the overall thrust of your question lacks crucial information.

Consider two analogies:

- Which is better, chocolate ice cream, or strawberry?  That's probably a matter of opinion, but at least both with serve similar purposes.
- Which is better, a jar of glue or a brick of C4?  That depends on whether you want to *build* something, or *blow something up*, doesn't it?

If you send a *copy* of data through a channel, the receiver gets ... a *copy*.  The receiver does not have access to the original.  The copying process may take some time, but the fact that the receiver does not have to *share* access may speed things up.  So this is something of an opinion, and if your question is about which is *faster*, well, you'll have to benchmark it.  Be sure to benchmark the real problem, and not a toy example, because benchmarks on toy examples don't translate to real-world performance.

If you send a *pointer to* data through a channel, the receiver gets a copy of the pointer, and can therefore modify the original data.  Copying the pointer is fast, but the fact that the receiver has to *share* access may slow things down.  But if the receiver *must* be able to modify the data, you have no choice.  You must use a tool that works, and not one that does not.

In your two functions, one *generates values* (`funcv`) so it does not *have to* send pointers.  That's fine, and gives you the option.  The other (`funcp`) *receives objects but wants to update them* so it *must* receive a pointer to the underlying object.  That's fine too, but it means that you are now communicating by sharing (the underlying data structure), which requires careful coordination.